# Please don't delete the "thank you" comment when the OP thanks the answerer

Tags: discussion

Taking the decision of accepting an answer among many answers is very hard as it implicitly may give the feeling of *"I like the other answer more than this"*

From a while ago, I asked a question and I got 2 answers. I accepted one of them and upvoted both, and commented something like "thank you very much for your help" for the non-accepted answer to reduce that embarrassing feeling. After a couple of minutes my comment is deleted!.

I understand that too many thank yous reduce the quality of the posts, but when this is my question I really like to thank the person who take from his own time and helped me.

**So please don't delete the OP comment when he thanks his answerer**

*(imagine that you take from your time and effort to help the OP and answer his question and the OP accepts other answer and completely ignores your answer -upvotes are anonymous-)*

Comment: Try to comment something more constructive, for example why you choose the other as accepted answer, after all we are building something for future users (that does not care about "Thank you" comments), the upvote is already stating "This is good stuff"

Comment: @Kendra:  Ooh, good point.  I'll reverse this.  Good catch!

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm now convinced of your deleted point about there is no need to the comment to stay as the answerer saw it once.

Comment: On the contrary, I always felt embarrassed when I receive a "thank you" comment. Do I need to reply with a "you're welcome"? If I don't maybe it seems impolite. But why do we need these chatty stuff in the first place ? I don't reply to these things, and I don't want to receive either.

Comment: @liliscent Hmm, never thought that.

Comment: A part of the reason that make Stack Overflow a very unwelcoming place for far too many. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

Answer (score 24):

Allow me to counter this with my own plea:

**Please don't use comments for what they are not made for.**

Comments are for clarification and adding more information. They are not for discussion, for answering/asking questions, or for "thank yous."

Our comment placeholders even state this is the purpose of comments.

Questions:

[image: Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments.]

Answers:

[image: Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".]

Now, if your comment was *more* than thanks, that's more of a grey area. For example, if you pointed out an especially helpful part of the post, that's arguably useful. But only *arguably.*

Comment: +1 Thanks...... and Kendra remember https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145551/acknowledging-thank-you-comments